# Is it required to define a route while calling form through formBuilder()

Tags: 8, forms, routes

Is it required to define a separate route while calling form through

```
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm();
```

Comment: No, use either a form route to have the form as main page content or embed the form somewhere else with formBuilder(). This is a great answer how to do this in a block https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223188/47547

Comment: What? What does route have anything to do with this?

Comment: Could please improve your question with the use case you have? You could have more accurate answers.